# Does Lync UCWA support chat rooms?

Tags: lync, ucwa

We have a local Lync installation. Is it possible to post and receives messages to a Lync chat room using UCWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCWA currently (CU2) does not have the ability to see or interact with Persistent Chat rooms.  If/when it is added there should be information at [UCWA Resources](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/reference-resources) describing how to interact with the resource.